# Angular 2 rc1: component does not have route configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript, routes, angular

First, I don't think this question is a duplication of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165839/component-does-not-have-route-configuration-nested-routes-angular2-rc1). If it is, sorry.

I'm working on an angular 2 application. Few weeks ago, I was using the beta15. I've decided to update to rc1 for some reasons :

- I prefer to update progressively instead of doing it one -long- time
- Doing this, I have to keep an eye on the changelog
- third parties follows the movement

Of course, I've encountered some issues, I've updated packages by hand
and clean my code.

But there is still an issue that I can't figure out. I have this error :
**`component does not have route configuration`**. I have nested routes.

The difference between the other issue is that my component isn't a child component, but the main component.

Here is my Routeconfig declaration (I'm using `router-deprecated` :

```
@RouteConfig([
         { path: '/home',    name: 'Home',   loader: () => Routes.lazyLoad('component@home', 'HomeComponent'),   useAsDefault: true },
         { path: '/media/...',  name: 'Media', loader: () => Routes.lazyLoad('component@media', 'MediaComponent') },
         { path: '/channel/...',  name: 'Channel', loader: () => Routes.lazyLoad('component@channel', 'ChannelComponent') },
         { path: '/playlist',  name: 'Playlist', loader: () => Routes.lazyLoad('component@home', 'HomeComponent') },
         { path: '/medias',  name: 'Medias', loader: () => Routes.lazyLoad('component@medias', 'MediasComponent') },
    ])
export class MainComponent {
    private prodEnv: boolean = initialState.prodEnv;
}
```

`Routes.lazyload()` is a really simple function that uses `SystemJS` to import components :

```
public static lazyLoad(ref: string, component: string): any {
        return System.import(ref)
            .then((m: any) => m[component])
            .catch((err: any) => {
                console.error(err);
                return err;
            });
    }
```

Of course, `Media` and `Channel` also have a `RouteConfig`.

Here is the MediasComponents's `RouteConfig`

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: 'add',          name: 'Add',        component: AddComponent,   useAsDefault: true },
    { path: 'manage',       name: 'Manage',     component: ManageComponent },
    { path: 'edit/:id',     name: 'Edit',       component: EditComponent }
])
```

ChannelComponent :

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: 'add',          name: 'Add',        component: AddComponent,   useAsDefault: true },
    { path: 'manage',       name: 'Manage',     component: ManageComponent },
    { path: 'manage/:id',   name: 'ManageId',   component: ManageComponent },
    { path: 'edit/:id',     name: 'Edit',       component: EditComponent }
])
```

Comment: This is not enough information. What is `Routes.lazyload()`? Do `Media`, `Channel`, and `Playlist` component have routes configured?

Comment: Are you sure you are bootstrapping the right component? Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Yep, I'm sure. I'll try to right a Plunker but I can't reproduce the exact same environment. I'll update my question when I'm done with this. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here is mine [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/RoVPZr6rRWlMpISrMj2R?p=preview). I can't reproduce the situation because of an error (that's why I haven't update my question yet). I post this comment in case you can help me on this sub-issue.

Comment: `app/parentA.component.ts` contains two `ChildAComponent` classes. If you have several classes in the same file, you can't refer to them before they appear in the file. You refer to them in the `@RouteConfig()` before they appeared in the file. Please fix the file names and move the component classes above `ParentAComponent`. Similar in `app/parentB.component.ts`. I could do it myself but I'm not sure what exactly the intention was (especially with the duplicate names)

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that I can't refer to classes declared after the use (maybe because in Javascript, variables declarations are moved to the top of their context during interpretation). Thanks. The plunk works well. So The issue seems to be deeper. I'm trying to find which part of my app can produce this and I'll update my question.

Comment: It's a common mistake. Classes are not hoisted like variables. Another way is to use `forwardRef(() => SomeClassBelow)` for example when there are circular references.

Comment: Okay so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Since this issue may be related to the `deprecated-router` and I don't have so much time to spend on it, I'll wait for the new router. When it'll be more complete, I'll update my code and if I still have the issue, I'll update this question to fit the update.

Comment: with router-deprecated, you can `import { ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT } from '@angular/router-deprectaed';` then you can `provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: AppComponent})` as part of the providers when bootstrapping your app: `bootstrap(AppComponent,[provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: AppComponent})]);` i cannot find a fix for this for the new router